# How do I handle complex relations with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

Although code-based answers are much appreciated, but I'm interested in knowing the logic behind handling this, as it might happen again later.

I'm working on an eCommerce project. Most products are variables. Imagine a shirt for example.

A shirt can have 5 different sizes ( XS, S, M, ML, L ) and 3 colors ( Red, Green, Blue ). These are examples, these attributes are dynamic and can be edited any time. My approach was to create 3 different tables for the product itself:

```
- main_product_table
    - id

- product_variant_table
    - id
    - main_product_id

- product_variant_combination_table
    - id
    - variant_id
    - attribute_name_id
    - attribute_value_id
```

And 2 more tables for the attributes:

```
- attribute_name_table
    - id
    - attribute_name

- attribute_value_table
    - id
    - attribute_value
```

So, for example the said shirt will now creates the following records:

- 2 records in `attribute_name_table`
- 3 records in `attribute_value_table`
- 1 record in `main_product_table`
- 3x5 records in the `product_variant_table`
- 2x3x5 records in the `product_variant_combination_table` ( 2 rows each holding the value of 1 attribute )

Now consider querying all products that include a XS size, or query the product with all of its variation data.

My questions are:

1. Can eloquent models handle this?
2. If so, should I create 5 models, 1 per table?
3. If not, should I create a single ( or 2 ) Models ( Product, Attribute ) and the connect them using custom SQLs and methods?
4. What are the relations here? Attributes seem to have one-to-many to me, but combinations also seem one-to-many and both of these are also connected to each other.

I'm struggling to understand the relations between the above. It seems understandable via SQL, but I can't relate them to each other via Eloquents.

Also, the tables seems to grow massive rapidly. Is this approach proper at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems very difficult to maintain in the long term. I don't understand why you would have to separate the name attribute from value.

I would create the product model, size and color with its migrations and a pivot table to store the stock

```
- size_table
-- id
-- name

- color_table
-- id
-- name

- product_table
-- id
-- type (shirt, pants, pullover ... etc.)
-- description
-- status

- stock_table
-- product_id (reference to the product table)
-- color_id (Reference to the color table)
-- size_id (Reference to the size table)
-- quantity (Quantity of products available with these attributes)
-- status
```

this way you have the same product with more than one combination stored in stock_table.

Now you only need to define the relationships between each model and then you will be able to access all the attributes from product_detail_table

```
$item->quantity
$item->product->description
$item->size->name
$item->color->name
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this answer does not help. Size and color are just examples. The attributes are dynamic, they can't be bound to columns. Also, they values are separated to maintain normalization. Otherwise you end up having tons of duplicate data.